# TypeScript empty object for a typed variable

Tags: typescript

Say I have:

```
type User = {
  ...
}
```

I want to create a new `user` but set it to be an empty object:

```
const user: User = {}; // This fails saying property XX is missing
const user: User = {} as any; // This works but I don't want to use any
```

How do I do this? I don't want the variable to be `null`.

Comment: Either you want `user` to be of type `User | {}` or `Partial<User>`, or you need to redefine the `User` type to allow an empty object.  Right now, the compiler is correctly telling you that `user` is not a `User`.

Answer (score 480, accepted):

## Caveats

Here are two worthy caveats from the comments.

> Either you want user to be of type `User | {}` or `Partial<User>`, or you need to redefine the `User` type to allow an empty object. Right now, the compiler is correctly telling you that user is not a User. – `jcalz`

> I don't think this should be considered a proper answer because it creates an inconsistent instance of the type, undermining the whole purpose of TypeScript. In this example, the property `Username` is left undefined, while the type annotation is saying it can't be undefined. – `Ian Liu Rodrigues`

## Answer

One of the [design goals of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) is to *"strike a balance between correctness and productivity."* If it will be productive for you to do this, use [Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to create empty objects for typed variables.

```
type User = {
    Username: string;
    Email: string;
}

const user01 = {} as User;
const user02 = <User>{};

user01.Email = "foo@bar.com";
```

Here is [a working example for you](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBT7BRAOwEMBbCALijmEQEsiBzAbh3ygFEyT6AbarQbM22AL44cAYwD2RWlACuhAAwBGVBjFQScAklGz5wJaoBMmgDzwkAPnRjROZUnUA6brz6aARADMZGQABACMSRDdZMh8WIA).

[image: Here are type assertions working with suggestion.]

Comment: Thank you! This solves it! This should be marked as the correct answer...

Comment: I don't think this should be considered a proper answer because it creates an inconsistent instance of the type, undermining the whole purpose of TypeScript. In this example, the property `Username` is left undefined, while the type annotation is saying it can't be undefined.

Comment: Good point @IanLiuRodrigues. I added some caveats to the answer.

Comment: @IanLiuRodrigues One of the goals of TypeScript is to balance correctness with productivity, so to say that this *undermines the whole purpose of TypeScript* is a bit extreme. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals

Comment: Maybe my typescript is just really bad but I find the language counter-productive. I just want to do something like this (c#) Define a person: public class Person { int age; } then later initialise a person that is either null or just with empty props: var p = new Person(); // with empty props or Person p = null; // starts off null Why should it be so complex?

Comment: OP doesn't want to use `any` because they've probably been warned against it. They've been warned against it because `any` doesn't protect them against runtime access errors, thereby defeating the point of using TypeScript (in a situation where subverting it probably isn't necessary or helpful).

This solution is exactly as bad as `any` because it asserts that attributes are present which are not which may cause downstream runtime errors.

Answer (score 55):

An empty object can be written as `Record<string,never>`, so effectively your type for user is either an empty object or a User

```
const user : User | Record<string, never> = {};
```

Comment: When I try to assign a value using `data[key] = 'test` I get the error `Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)` any idea?

Comment: you can only assing an empty object or a user. Thats what we are declaring. If you want to assign string do an or like so const user : User | Record<string, never> = {}|string;

Answer (score 31):

Really depends on what you're trying to do. Types are documentation in typescript, so you want to show intention about how this thing is supposed to be used when you're creating the type.

## Option 1: If Users might have some but not all of the attributes during their lifetime

Make all attributes optional

```
type User = {
  attr0?: number
  attr1?: string
}
```

## Option 2: If variables containing Users may begin null

```
type User = {
...
}
let u1: User = null;
```

Though, really, here if the point is to declare the User object before it can be known what will be assigned to it, you probably want to do `let u1:User` without any assignment.

## Option 3: What you probably want

Really, the premise of typescript is to make sure that you are conforming to the mental model you outline in types in order to avoid making mistakes. If you want to add things to an object one-by-one, this is a habit that TypeScript is trying to get you not to do.

More likely, you want to make some local variables, then assign to the User-containing variable when it's ready to be a full-on User. That way you'll never be left with a partially-formed User. Those things are gross.

```
let attr1: number = ...
let attr2: string = ...
let user1: User = {
  attr1: attr1,
  attr2: attr2
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what he is going for or not, but it is possible that we are talking about a seperate argument called UserAttributes or something that handles incoming parameters. It might not be an acceptable user object, and thus it could be defined seperately.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  Please see Shaun Luttin's post below.

Comment: Option 3 is so obvious and so good! Thank you!

Comment: @thargenediad why? It breaks type consistency in a way not intended by the language. If a downstream dev calls user01.name, they'll get a runtime error which TypeScript should prevent.  

It's a classic XY problem-- OP is really asking how to initialize an object, but they're asking about a solution they've come up with instead of asking the root question.

Creating a partial object as suggested by unflores could also work well here.

Answer (score 14):

Note that using `const user = {} as UserType` just provides intellisense but at runtime `user` is empty object `{}` and has no property inside. that means `user.Email` will give `undefined` instead of `""`

```
type UserType = {
    Username: string;
    Email: string;
}
```

So, use `class` with `constructor` for actually creating objects with default properties.

```
type UserType = {
  Username: string;
  Email: string;
};

class User implements UserType {
  constructor() {
    this.Username = "";
    this.Email = "";
  }

  Username: string;
  Email: string;
}

const myUser = new User();
console.log(myUser); // output: {Username: "", Email: ""}
console.log("val: "+myUser.Email); // output: ""
```

**You can also use `interface` instead of `type`**

```
interface UserType {
  Username: string;
  Email: string;
};
```

...and rest of code remains same.

---

Actually, you can even skip the `constructor` part and use it like this:

```
class User implements UserType {
      Username = ""; // will be added to new obj
      Email: string; // will not be added
}

const myUser = new User();
console.log(myUser); // output: {Username: ""}
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case `Record<string, never>` helps, it was recommended by eslint
[image: Eslint recommendations]

Comment: However if I have a union type of `type Foo = { a: { b: string } } | Record<string, never>` and I use it in the function parameter, `function bar(foo: Foo) { console.log(foo.a.b) }` will not error.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".

- If you want a type meaning "empty object", you probably want `Record<string, never>` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `object` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
user: USER

this.user = ({} as USER)
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please

Answer (score 3):

you can do this as below in typescript

```
 const _params = {} as any;

 _params.name ='nazeh abel'
```

since typescript does not behave like javascript so we have to make the type as any otherwise it won't allow you to assign property dynamically to an object

Comment: If you use `as any` you might as well not use TypeScript. Never do this.

Answer (score 1):

What i wanted is `intellisense` help for a chain of middlewares. `Record<string, never>` worked for me.

```js
type CtxInitialT = Record<string, never>;
type Ctx1T = CtxInitialT & {
  name: string;
};
type Ctx2T = Ctx1T & {
  token: string;
};

cont ctx: CtxInitialT = {};
// ctx.name = ''; // intellisense error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
cont ctx1: Ctx1T = middleware1AugmentCtx(ctx);
// ctx1.name = 'ddd'; // ok
// ctx1.name1 = ''; // intellisense error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
cont ctx2: Ctx2T = middleware2AugmentCtx(ctx1);
// ctx2.token = 'ttt'; // ok
// ctx2.name1 = ''; // intellisense error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an empty object literal and then assign values later on, then you can consider those values optional (may or may not be there), so just type them as optional with a question mark:

```
type User = {
    Username?: string;
    Email?: string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case of

```
type User = {
    Username?: string;
    Email?: string;
}
```

you can declare an empty object or only one field(for example, only Username); in that case, you will not have an error, which can be a problem.

I will prefer more {} as `User` version.

Comment: It's bad practice to use optional parameters and optional stuff.

Comment: Call me crazy but isn't this exactly similar to @CatalinBerta 's solution which was answered 3 years before yours?