# Typing an object created dynamically through a loop in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type like this:

```js
type Wrapper<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        value: T[K];
        meta: string[];
    }
}
```

I have a function `createWrapper` that takes an object and creates a wrapper out of it:

```js
const createWrapper = <T extends object>(obj: T): Wrapper<T> => {
    let wrapper: any = {};
    for (let key in obj) {
        wrapper[key] = {
            value: obj[key],
            meta: []
        };
    }
    return wrapper as Wrapper<T>;
}
```

How could I type the object creation inside `createWrapper` to avoid `any` and `as Wrapper<T>` types?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript empty object for a typed variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339065/typescript-empty-object-for-a-typed-variable)

Comment: @JurajKocan I actually want to avoid type assertions. The question you mentioned provides type assertions as an alternative to null. I want to know if there is a way for TypeScript to detect that every key of T is assigned to the new object and therefore it satisfies the type.

Comment: [this if is the problem?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzJOAeAKgPigXigbwFgAoKKAbQGkoBLAOygGsIQB7AMynQF0AuAkmTIA3BABsArhH7oq3ANyChAWwjAE-AM7A49AObkFSgL4lji4iQDGrOtqhW4EBMAjwkKXFAxQIAD1c6ABNNKFYAIwArCCtgTAAKCMiZAEp+d2QINCxcbCJSB1t7AHdETLh0spQMbDx8YygEUIzqrAslAHoOqGBNMXpgXiCaTQRwsQgAWjp-YEn+md52Vl06JWW4KHibO2AmFloGJJSBArIaTnjmEFwcPAByAEYAZnuT-KEhcKcERgtP0xnKClDxZcjXRqha4cLjcLwfT5QUSSaRhKLgljcAA0Sk+qnU-EMOKB5hMSicwAkcAYIPKkNgVSyNQs5iAA)  well... interesting, i cant find any ts solution for this

Comment: If you want your runtime code to stay the same, you pretty much need type assertions.  You can make it a bit better by writing `let wrapper: Partial<Wrapper<T>> = {}` instead of using `any`.  But after the loop the compiler will not understand by itself that all the keys are present. You can make user-defined type guards, but a well-placed assertion is probably your best bet here.