# How to set key/value default state for TypeScript React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having to convert a React app to Typescript and I can't figure out to property set the initial state of hash object.

original js

```
export default class Wizard extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = this.initialState();
    }



    /** Setup Steps */
    initialState = () => {
        const state = {
            activeStep: 0,
            hashKeys: {},
        };

        // Set initial classes
        // Get hash only in client side
        const hash = typeof window === 'object' ? this.getHash() : '';
        const children = React.Children.toArray(this.getSteps());
        children.forEach((child, i) => {
            // Create hashKey map
            state.hashKeys[i] = (child.props && child.props.hashKey) || `step${i + 1}`;
            state.hashKeys[state.hashKeys[i]] = i;
        });

        ...

        return state;
    }
...
```

My Failed Attempt

```
export interface TState {
  activeStep?: number
  hashKeys: {
    [key: number]: string
  }
}

export default class StepWizard extends PureComponent<{},TState> {
   constructor(props: IStepWizardProps) {
       super(props)
       this.state = this.initialState()
   }

   initialState = () => {
    const state = {
      activeStep: 0,
      hashKeys: {},  /* <---- This seems to be the problem */
    }

    // Set initial classes
    // Get hash only in client side
    const hash = typeof window === "object" ? this.getHash() : ""

    const children = React.Children.toArray(this.getSteps())
    children.forEach((child, i) => {
      // Create hashKey map
      // the following give a TS error
      // ERROR: (property) hashKeys: {}
      //           Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' 
      //           can't be used to index type '{}'.
      //        No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)
      state.hashKeys[i] = (child.props && child.props.hashKey) || `step${i + 1}`
      state.hashKeys[state.hashKeys[i]] = i
    })

   ...
```

I get for `state.hasKeys[i]` (property) hashKeys: {}
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the definition of hashKeys as `{}`.

Typescript doesn't know what the types of data will be for the key/value, but, you can tell it!

```js
const hashKeys = {} as Record<number, string>;

const x = hashKeys[0];
```

For your example:

```js
        const state = {
            activeStep: 0,
            hashKeys: {} as Record<string, string>, // or whatever your types are
        };
```

Comment: would `const state: TState = { activeStep: 0, hashKeys: {} }` work too?

Comment: @Thankyou [Indeed it would!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoGUx0sg3gKGWUTGADcJMIAHAfgC5kQBXAWwCNpDkALOAZx4BpCAE9+jAkSIBtANZjGLDtAC6jfmCigA5twC++Q-nwIA9iE3JN2CIwxYcAXjzciJcpUjVGABgA0brwCwmISePqB+gDcJqYWVgAeyC42kAB0fIIi4jK+qtFAA)

Comment: Much appreciated. I am learning a lot from your TS answers :D

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: [Type Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)

```js
export interface TState {
  activeStep?: number;
  hashKeys: {
    [key: number]: string
  } | {};
}
```

This syntax indicates that `hashKeys` could take the shape of either `{[key: number]: string}` or `{}`.

If you wanted to improve the readability of that union, you could do this:

```js
type HashMap = {
  [key: number]: string;
}

export interface TState {
  activeStep?: number;
  hashKeys: HashMap | {};
}
```

### Option 2: [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) (pssst probably not optimal - see option 3)

`Partial` constructs a type with all properties set to optional, which means that `{}` fits the definition by having both non-existent key and value properties.

```js
type HashMap = {
  [key: number]: string;
}

export interface TState {
  activeStep?: number;
  hashKeys: Partial<HashMap>
}
```

## Option 3: [Type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

[As pointed out in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45339463/129086), this approach does a better job of striking "a balance between correctness and productivity."

```js
type HashMap = {
  [key: number]: string;
}

export interface TState {
  activeStep?: number;
  hashKeys: HashMap;
}

//

const state = {
  activeStep: 0,
  hashKeys: {} as HashMap,
};
```