# Programatically create a typed Record / Object from the keys of another one

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my typescript program (code below) I define two base types (`Player`, `State`) and then a few nested `Record` types used as mappings.

I then in a typed function create an instance of one of these records based on an existing instance of the nested record.

```
type Player = "1" | "2";
type State = "A" | "B" | "C";
type StateMapping = Record<State, State>;
type PlayerStateMappings = Record<Player, StateMapping>
type PlayerStates = Record<Player, State>;

const playerStateMappings: PlayerStateMappings = {
    "1": {
        "A": "B",
        "B": "C",
        "C": "A"
    },
    "2": {
        "C": "B",
        "B": "A",
        "A": "C"
    },
}

function nextStates(currentState: State): PlayerStates {
    var nextStates = {};
    for(const player of Object.keys(playerStateMappings)){
        nextStates[player] = playerStateMappings[player][currentState]
    }
    return nextStates;
}

console.log(nextStates("A"))
```

This code throws the following type error at the return statement, since I created the object without the required keys and only added those afterwards:
`TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'PlayerStates': 1, 2`.

**My question is if there is a way to avoid this type error that fulfils the following requirements**:

1. The typesystem is not relaxed in particular it still enforces that the `nextStates` function returns a complete and valid `PlayerStates` object.
2. The `nextStates` object is created programatically based on the keys of the `playerStatesMapping` object, meaning I don't have to hardcode all of the players again.

After some research on SO I found a few options that avoid the error but all of which violate one of the two requirements mentioned above:

Approaches that violate condition 1:

1. Make the PlayerStates type partial: `type PlayerStates = Partial<Record<Player, State>>;`
2. Enforce type using `as` keyword: `var nextStates = {} as PlayerStates`; (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339065/typescript-empty-object-for-a-typed-variable) question)

Approaches that violate condition 2:

1. Set a default value for each Player in the object creation: `var nextStates = {"1": "A", "2": "B"}`

I know that the whole typing is a bit of an overkill in the above example but this is a highly simplified / reduced version of the problem that I encountered in a more complex project where above requirements / expectations make more sense.

PS: Coming from a python background I guess I am looking for something like a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) that allows me to initialize a new dictionary based on some iteration.

Comment: Why “Enforce type using as keyword” violate point 1? IMO it doesn’t.

Comment: @hackape: Because then the type system would not enforce that I return a complete `PlayerStates` Record. For example the following code would typecheck:
```
function nextStates(currentState: State): PlayerStates {
    var nextStates = {} as PlayerStates;
    return nextStates;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off @hackape's answer I was able to produce the following, but it required redefining `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries`:

```
type Player = "1" | "2";
type State = "A" | "B" | "C";
type StateMapping = Record<State, State>;
type PlayerStateMappings = Record<Player, StateMapping>
type PlayerStates = Record<Player, State>;

const playerStateMappings: PlayerStateMappings = {
    "1": {
        "A": "B",
        "B": "C",
        "C": "A"
    },
    "2": {
        "C": "B",
        "B": "A",
        "A": "C"
    },
}

// stricter version of Object.entries
const entries: <T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: T) => Array<[keyof T, T[keyof T]]> = Object.entries

// stricter version of Object.fromEntries
const fromEntries: <K extends PropertyKey, V>(entries: Iterable<readonly [K, V]>) => Record<K, V> = Object.fromEntries

function nextStates(currentState: State): PlayerStates {
  return fromEntries(
    entries(playerStateMappings).map(([player, mapping]) =>
      [player, mapping[currentState]]
    )
  )
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQxBATlAvFARARi1AH2wCYsBuAKFEigGVgFhpMsBBfIrAIQ+wGFyVcNHqMIAWQRgwASwB2AcwxQAShADGAexQATADyimAGjoMmAPkrVo8JKkMSpsxQGdlarbr23kKEw8lpeQVzIRofezMIN0wPbX0Iv1MxSwoKLTkXYCgwRF8Ap2CXAC5YPMixQOcFGKgAbwooJuw8Uobmjux2Uu4sI0bOpt6egX7BoYEe9gGmgF8x5qxSNpnOrEnsHgXB4a6+1Y62LBGsVfmKWbSAeiuoLJQZdSY0ADdUFxlNOShNADMoADyACMAFYaYAAOggcmAD2i6S+WSg0NhMmipT0ABVkQAPJhyHRuOJeGAoTSQFCgADSEBAJgArnIANZyTQAdzk5nMAApNKDSpiAJQYcxQVgoFBIPQAbSZtL+UExJkxsvl-0xAF0NaLMMCwU8oTC4S5rrd7o9nlA3igPl8fv89eCIb8yQBbACiRrRJoySJdmg9XvRUD0VNx+MJsDJFOptJMADUeSjjaUAJLPBBAuAQPQoCAIHRfOAgKDSqkJ7XC9Ci4n6ctQRPKR0G-2B1Hwii-RlPT7fOQQPEOFzc9T0iUohylByC0qJIf1AZ54Bj76tz3t4erZPe7m5OwoApBVyCiGuqTc7nSve+Exno8KDVV0KDK-lJJ36rS0fjmEOLWrQUBkA2YgA)

Comment: Or the lazy man’s `as Player` trick works too. I think it’s legit, cus we know it’s a fact.

Comment: Sure - though personally I think it's always better to avoid overriding the compiler where it's practical/possible

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, this does seem to work and ticks all of my boxes. Could you maybe give a hint as to the idea behind the redefinition of `entries` and `fromEntries`. I have a little difficulty wrapping my head around it (I am new to typescript).

Comment: Unfortunately I just realised that this answer does somehow seem to relax the typing system as it does not really enforce the `nextStates` function to return a full `PlayerStates` object. If I declare the `PlayerStateMappings` partial and remove one of the player entries from `playerStateMappings` the code still typechecks even though the return value of `nextStates` is not a valid `PlayerStates` object anymore.

Comment: Interestingly in the Typescript Playground above described change does throw an error but when I run the file using `ts-node` it typechecks without error. (Even though `nextStates` will return an invalid `PlayerState` object)

Answer (score 1):

Try the functional programming way. You can avoid using the `nextStates` variable altogether. Problem gone.

```js
function nextStates(currentState: State): PlayerStates {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(playerStateMappings).map(([player as Player, mapping]) =>
      [player, mapping[currentState]]
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile for me. I got an error saying: `Type '{ [k: string]: State; }' is missing the following properties from type 'PlayerStates': 1, 2`

Comment: I just type it out on a cellphone. Can you share a TS playground? It’s hard for me to setup.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQxBATlAvFARARi1AH2wCYsBuAKFEigGVgFhpMsBBfIrAIQ+wGFyVcNHqMIAWQRgwASwB2AcwxQAShADGAexQATADyimAGjoMmAPkrVo8JKkMSpsxQGdlarbr23kKEw8lpeQVzIRofezMIN0wPbX0Iv1MxSwoKLTkXYCgwRF8Ap2CXAC5YPMixQOcFGKgAbwooJuw8Uobmjux2Uu4sI0bOpt6egX7BoYEe9gGmgF8x5qxSNpnOrEnsHgXB4a6+1Y62LBGsVfmKWbSAMwBXOXVgGU05KDkIAA9gBxcACnUblAoCByL5RUoOACUpUS33qAyBwABLwA8gAjABWGmAADorihNABbACiIJQMmiP1WaMxD2xwOAZIpuTsKAKQVcEOxBKkPx+AG1mb4TNz2QoALoQjChQYC8pJEXVPn-QH0hxisWrCEDLWzIA

Comment: Ah I see. It’s due to the TS stock typing of standard lib is actually kinda conservative. `Object.entries<T>` COULD infer `entry[0]` to be `keyof T` but it doesn’t, instead it just infer `string` which is playing safe.

Comment: That should be easy to fix, let me try it

Comment: Yeah, you can augment the stock typing if you want. I’m lazy, I just go `([player as Player, mapping])` 

Answer (score 0):

The type error is from your `nextStates` variable as you haven't specified it's type so it's inferred as `{}` when you define it as the empty object.

You can use a `Partial` type only for your `nextStates` variable to allow it to start off empty, but you will need a way to tell the compiler when the full `PlayerStates` object has been created using a guard. Here's an example:

```
type Player = "1" | "2";
type State = "A" | "B" | "C";
type StateMapping = Record<State, State>;
type PlayerStateMappings = Record<Player, StateMapping>
type PlayerStates = Record<Player, State>;

const playerStateMappings: PlayerStateMappings = {
    "1": {
        "A": "B",
        "B": "C",
        "C": "A"
    },
    "2": {
        "C": "B",
        "B": "A",
        "A": "C"
    },
}

// Stricter version of keys which returns Array<keyof T> instead of string[]
const keys = <T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> =>
  Object.keys(obj);

// Type guard to convert Partial<PlayerStates> to PlayerStates
const isCompletePlayerStatesObj = (
  obj: Partial<PlayerStates>
): obj is PlayerStates => 
  obj["1"] !== undefined && obj["2"] !== undefined;

function nextStates(currentState: State): PlayerStates {
    var nextStates: Partial<PlayerStates> = {};

    for(const player of keys(playerStateMappings)){
        nextStates[player] = playerStateMappings[player][currentState]
    }

    if (!isCompletePlayerStatesObj(nextStates)) {
      throw new Error("Whoops this function was badly implemented")
    }

    return nextStates;
}

console.log(nextStates("A"));
```

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion.  I would like to avoid having to hard code / list all of the players again one by one as you did in the function you added (I probably should have formulated requirement 2 better). Also I am using the typing system here to catch more errors at compile / typecheck time. As I understand your solution would relax the typing system and replace it with a runtime check, which is not really ideal.

Comment: I don't think it's possible then. The best option IMO would be to have an initial `PlayerStates` object that you can use as a starting point instead of an empty object.

Comment: Yeah, that is the way I have currently implemented it. It just feels very verbose / suboptimal. Essentially I want to have the list of players in only one place since these base types contain many more values that will probably frequently change, which is why I want to avoid writing them all out again.

Comment: I agree it's verbose. At least the compiler will complain to you if you are missing a player in the initial `PlayerStates` object. So as soon as you add a player the compiler will tell you that you need to update that object.

Comment: I've added a new answer based on @hackape's suggestion which works :)