# Why can't Data, which extends {}, be assigned to {}? Does {} != {}?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why this code errors. Could someone help me? I have looked all around stack overflow and found a lot of way too specific examples of this, but I don't understand the most basic question. Why can't Data, which extends {}, be assigned to {}? Does {} != {}?

```
function fn<Data extends {}>(data: Data = {}) { }
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
```

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Data'. '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Data', but 'Data' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2322)

Comment: Why are you extending `{}`?

Comment: I want the user of this function to be able to pass in any object. Basically, it should prevent passing in primitive values.

Comment: @JacobWeisenburger okey. Followup question. Why do you need `data` to have a default value?

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking, but yes, `{} != {}`.

Comment: @Olian04 because I want data to be an empty object instead of undefined if no value is passed.

Comment: I don't really see why you'd need the generic parameter at all. Why not just `fn(data: Record<string, any>)`? Unless you are going to manually pass the type parameter to enable intellisense (which defeats the purpose of using a default value), there's no good reason for it. I think you should reconsider your reasoning for both the type parameter and default value; they don't make sense together. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Because the type of `Data` could be something that requires properties not present in `{}`.

Say, for example, you create the following interface:

```ts
interface FooData {
  foo: string
}
```

We know we cannot do this:

```ts
const data: FooData = {};
//                    ^^ - missing required property `foo: string`
```

Yet that's exactly what you are attempting in your `fn` declaration when you set the default value to `{}`. In TypeScript's words:

> '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Data', but 'Data' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.

In this case, `FooData` is the *"different subtype of constraint '{}'"* that requires property `foo`, which is not present on `{}`. **`{}` does not guarantee that the type parameter passed to `Data` will be satisfied by `{}`, so `{}` is not allowed as a default.**

---

Also, you probably meant to extend type `Record<string, any>` instead. `{}`, [the empty type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#empty-types), is often not what you want (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68895699/how-to-access-object-properties-of-possible-empty-object-in-typescript/68927087#68927087)) as it will allow everything except for `null` and `undefined`.

**Note**: in most cases, it is not feasible to define a default value for a generically typed parameter since the actual type can be more specific than the default value (as explained above).

Comment: I want the user of this function to be able to pass in any object. Basically, it should prevent passing in primitive values. Is there a different way to allow any object without allowing primitive values?

Comment: @JacobWeisenburger do you need to use generics? Otherwise simply `data: Object = {}` would suffice.