# How to set up the initial state in pinia using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I having some problems when adding typescript to a pinia store, so I would like to know hpw can I solve this issue, this project is using pinia:^2.0.16 and Vue:3.2.37

This is the error:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Order': id,
> user_id, total, user, products

```
import type { ShoppingCart } from '@/Models/ShoppingCart'
import type { Product } from '@/Models/Product'

const initialState : ShoppingCart = {
  products: [],
  cart: [],
  order: {}, // <- here is the typescript error
}

export const useShoppingCart = defineStore('shoppingcart', {
  persist: true,
  state: () => (initialState),
  actions: {
    addToCart(product: Product) {
      ....
    },
    removeFromCart(){
    .....
    },
   ...
   ...
}
```

Models/ShoppingCart.ts

```
import type { Order } from './Order'
import type { Product } from './Product'

export interface ShoppingCart {
  products: Product[]
  cart: Product[]
  order: Order
}
```

Models/Order.ts

```
import type { User } from './User'
import type { Product } from './Product'
export interface Order {
  id: number
  user_id: number
  total: number
  user: User
  products: Product[]
}
```

Models/Product.ts

```
import type { Category } from '@/Models/Category'

export interface Product {
  id: number
  name: string
  slug: string
  description: string
  price: number
  categories: Category[]
  quantity: number
}
```

Models/Category.ts

```
import type { Product } from '@/Models/Product'
export interface Category {
  id: number
  name: string
  slug: string
  products?: Product[]
}
```

Models/User.ts

```
import type { Order } from './Order'

export interface User {
  id: number
  name: string
  email: string
  orders: Order[]
}
```

I am getting the typescript error in the **order** property of the **InitialState**:

```
const initialState : ShoppingCart = {
  products: [],
  cart: [],
  order: {}, // <- here is the typescript error
}
```

How can I solve this error please? thank you

Comment: Do you really want to have empty object as default state? It could null which would make more sense, but if you really want it you should update your ShoppingCart interface like this  `order: Order | {}`. Actually there are more possibilities, check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339065/typescript-empty-object-for-a-typed-variable

Comment: @NikitaChayka thanks for responding, one question, why is it not ok the order state to be an empty object? currently products and cart are empty arrays and they are not showing errors

Comment: I mean it is ok I guess, depends on the needs, I would do it null just cause you have no order initially, I would use empty object only in case if that should represent some sort of placeholder which then is being populated.  Just an opinion though, I'm not saying that your way is bad

Comment: Setting it to null is preferable, since all parameters are required, hence an empty object is a contradiction. So it should be  `Order | null`.

Comment: @cwillinx thanks for responding, now it is not showing errors, but I wonder why in products and cart is not showing errors, because those are empty arrays. thanks

Comment: @DeveloperX Typescript is understanding that it is an empty array of type Product[].
e.g. setting it to `products: ['not a product'],` till be a type error since a string is not a Product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to have it as proper answer as mentioned in the comments above, the object should be null.

```
const initialState : ShoppingCart = {
    products: [],
    cart: [],
    order: null,
}
```

and therefore

```
export interface ShoppingCart {
    products: Product[]
    cart: Product[]
    order: Order | null
}
```